# Checking existing row and update same item number with two different quantity using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am making an inventory control system and I am getting a problem in updating the balance. The problem is that if I am purchasing same item with different price it is just updating balance of first row.

See lines given below:

```
itemcode item quantity price
------------------------------
101      CPU  10       6000/-
101      CPU  15       6500/-
```

Suppose I am passing these values in datatable and then I pass these values to stored procedure as a parameter and in stored procedure I am writing below given lines:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT t.itemno, t.department 
           FROM @itemupdate AS t 
           INNER JOIN item_detail p ON t.itemno = p.itemno  
                                    AND t.department = p.department)
BEGIN
    --update existing record
    UPDATE item_detail 
    SET purqt = item_detail.purqt + t.purqt 
    FROM @itemupdate AS t 
    WHERE t.itemno = item_detail.itemno 
      AND t.department = item_detail.department 
END
ELSE
BEGIN   
    --insert new record
    INSERT INTO item_detail 
       SELECT
           t.itemno, t.itemname, t.purqt, t.unit, t.department 
       FROM 
           @itemupdate t    
END
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have department in your datatable? Your sample seems to indicate you do not.- If not try doing so.

Comment: yes department is in datatable...sorry i have forgot to write in my sample